# How do I traverse this Ruby object?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using the [Oga gem](https://gitlab.com/yorickpeterse/oga), and I did this:

```
@output   = document.xpath('//li/a')
```

That produced this output:

```
> #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648 @titles=NodeSet(Element(name: "a" attributes: [Attribute(name: "href" value: "/market-data/index-data/jse-index")] children: NodeSet(Text("\n\n                \n\n\n                JSE Index \n                \n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                4,614,305 Vol\n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                                299,175.87                \n                "), Element(name: "img" attributes: [Attribute(name: "style" value: "height:16px"), Attribute(name: "src" value: "/img/down.png")]), Text("\n\n                \n                -541.06\n                            "))), Element(name: "a" attributes: [Attribute(name: "href" value: "/market-data/index-data/all-jamaican")] children: NodeSet(Text("\n\n                \n\n\n                JSE All Jamaican Composite Index \n                \n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                3,911,832 Vol\n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                                328,363.09                \n                "), Element(name: "img" attributes: [Attribute(name: "style" value: "height:16px"), Attribute(name: "src" value: "/img/down.png")]), Text("\n\n                \n                -593.84\n                            "))), Element(name: "a" attributes: [Attribute(name: "href" value: "/market-data/index-data/jse-select")] children: NodeSet(Text("\n\n                \n\n\n                JSE Select Index \n                \n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                3,036,580 Vol\n                "),
```

I am not sure how to actually traverse this object though.

I have tried the normal Ruby methods (for Arrays, Hashes, etc.) and they don't work. I even tried those for the [NodeSet object in Nokogiri](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/1.5.0/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) but to no avail...for example:

```
>>  @output.titles
NoMethodError: undefined method `titles' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>
    from /app/views/portfolio/ticker.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_portfolio_ticker_html_erb__2987784693093146087_70315110554280'
>>  @output[:titles]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>
    from /app/views/portfolio/ticker.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_portfolio_ticker_html_erb__2987784693093146087_70315110554280'
>>  @output.at_xpath('a')
NoMethodError: undefined method `at_xpath' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>
    from /app/views/portfolio/ticker.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_portfolio_ticker_html_erb__2987784693093146087_70315110554280'
```

How do I get access to that data in that object?

Comment: Nothing in your sample code assigns anything to `@output`; that's the behavior you are getting. `titles` behaves like an array and you can enumerate it with standard methods. Try `titles[0].path`, for example.

Comment: @Phlip there is more code, but for the sake of previty, assume that it is properly assigned. I have updated the question to be more accurate.

Comment: @Phlip I also tried your suggestion and it didn't work: `>  @output[0].path
NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>`

Answer (score 2):

Your output tells you that you have an instance of `GrabFeedFromJSE`:

> ```
> #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648 @titles=NodeSet(Element(name: "a" attributes: [Attribute(name: "href" value: "/market-data/index-data/jse-index")] children: NodeSet(Text("\n\n                \n\n\n                JSE Index \n                \n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                4,614,305 Vol\n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                                299,175.87                \n                "), Element(name: "img" attributes: [Attribute(name: "style" value: "height:16px"), Attribute(name: "src" value: "/img/down.png")]), Text("\n\n                \n                -541.06\n                            "))), Element(name: "a" attributes: [Attribute(name: "href" value: "/market-data/index-data/all-jamaican")] children: NodeSet(Text("\n\n                \n\n\n                JSE All Jamaican Composite Index \n                \n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                3,911,832 Vol\n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                                328,363.09                \n                "), Element(name: "img" attributes: [Attribute(name: "style" value: "height:16px"), Attribute(name: "src" value: "/img/down.png")]), Text("\n\n                \n                -593.84\n                            "))), Element(name: "a" attributes: [Attribute(name: "href" value: "/market-data/index-data/jse-select")] children: NodeSet(Text("\n\n                \n\n\n                JSE Select Index \n                \n                "), Element(name: "br"), Text("\n\n                3,036,580 Vol\n                "), 
>   ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
>
> >>  @output.titles
> NoMethodError: undefined method `titles' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>
>                                                ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
>   from /app/views/portfolio/ticker.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_portfolio_ticker_html_erb__2987784693093146087_70315110554280'
> >>  @output[:titles]
> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>
>                                            ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
>   from /app/views/portfolio/ticker.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_portfolio_ticker_html_erb__2987784693093146087_70315110554280'
> >>  @output.at_xpath('a')
> NoMethodError: undefined method `at_xpath' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>
>                                                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
>   from /app/views/portfolio/ticker.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_portfolio_ticker_html_erb__2987784693093146087_70315110554280'
> >> @output[0].path
> NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for #<GrabFeedFromJSE:0x00007fe7098bb648>
>                                            ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
> ```

You will have to look up its documentation in order to know how you can access it.

If you simply want to know what methods it has, you can use Ruby reflection to do that, e.g.

```
@output.methods          # to get a list of methods
m = @output.method(:foo) # to get a specific method
m.owner                  # to find out which module the method belongs to
```

And so on.

Note: You are using a completely different XML processor, so using Nokogiri's documentation won't help you one bit. You need to look at Oga's documentation. However, the object you are dealing with, is not an Oga object, it is a `GrebFeedFromJSE` object. You should look up its documentation, or contact its author, if it doesn't have documentation.

Comment: I am the author of the `GrabFeedFromJSE` class, but all that class does is returns the results from this: `@output   = document.xpath('//li/a')` So technically it is an Oga object.